# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' (Statement: nu+=int(j[:l])+int(j[l:]))

Tags: python

Wrote a program to find modified Kaprekar number in a range.

Here's the full question: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/kaprekar-numbers/problem

And here's my code:

```
def kaprekarNumbers(p, q):
    arr = []
    for i in range(p, q):
        nu = 0
        j = str(i*i)
        l = int(len(j)/2)
        nu+=int(j[:l])+int(j[l:])
        if nu == i:
            arr.append(i)  
    if len(arr) == 0:
        print('INVALID RANGE')
    else:
        print(arr)

This is the error: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 29, in <module>
    kaprekarNumbers(p, q)
  File "Solution.py", line 16, in kaprekarNumbers
    nu+=int(j[:l])+int(j[l:])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your code does not account for single digit numbers. So for example, let's say `i` is 1-

- `j = str(1 * 1)` => `j = '1'`
- `l = int(len('1') / 2)` => `l = 0`
- `j[:0]` => `'1'`, valid to cast to `int`
- `j[0:]` => `''`, invalid cast - empty string

You should make sure that if `j[:0]` or `j[0:]` is an empty string, turn it into `0`.

Comment: For example `nu = int(j[l:]) + (int(j[:l]) if l > 0 else 0)`